# change shutdown sequence to avoid nfs umount failure

Tags: debian, nfs, raspbian

I am running strain of raspbian (debian-based) on my Raspberry Pi, and during reboots, the device seems to hang on shutdown while trying to unmount an NFS directory...

```
....
[ok] Stopping Network connection manager: wcid.
.....
[[timestamp]] nfs: server freenas not responding, still trying
```

Looks to me like its waiting for a response from NFS despite already having stopped networking on the device. This will hang for 5 minutes or sometimes until I unplug it (i've waited as much as 30 minutes)

Is there a way to reorder this shutdown sequence so this doesn't happen?

Answer (score 1):

Check the shutdown sequence here:

```
ls /etc/rc6.d
```

Notice that `umountnfs.sh` has a higher number than network-manager or in your case wicd. Rename `umountnfs.sh`. In my case:

```
mv /etc/rc6.d/K06umountnfs.sh /etc/rc6.d/K02umountnfs.sh
```

And shutdown and reboot work in a normal way again.

Instructions from https://www.kubuntuforums.net/archive/index.php/t-55814.html